Difficulty training PPO agent for robotic arm navigation task
﻿
I'm currently working on training a PPO agent for a robotic arm navigation task, where the goal is to navigate the robotic arm to different positions in the environment. I've been training the agent for 5000 epochs, but it seems to converge to a fixed path.
﻿
I'm wondering if this is a normal behavior or if there's something wrong with my training setup. My reward function ranges from -15 to -0.2 when the arm doesn't reach the final position.
﻿Here are some additional training details:
Environment steps per episode: 150
Batch size: 2400 steps (5 training_cycles per batch)
Clipping coefficient: 0.2
Learning rate: 2e-4
Attached are the loss and reward curves during training. The x-axis represents the number of training.

Any insights or suggestions on how to improve the training process would be greatly appreciated.
﻿
Thanks in advance!

Try two things:

in the agent change to a beta distribution in case you used a normal (gaussian) one
clip the reward to the range [-1, 1]

